# how to create a global counter function that will be used in any viewController - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, global-variables

.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface globalFunction : NSObject{

    int nbr;
    }
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger myInt;

+(void)eventCount:(NSString*) eventName;

@end
```

.m file

```
@synthesize myInt;


+(void)eventCount:(NSString *)eventName{


    myInt ++;
    NSLog(@"Event name %@ and the count %d",eventName, myInt);


    }
```

but this gives me error of  Instance variable myInt accessed in class method.

As i searched google, it turned out the problem fixes when i change my global method sign (+) to instance function (-)

but i need a global method where i can use in any of viewController that help me get the count of how many times a specific thing happened during the session.

How can i proceed on this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use singelton Class to for global counter:

like:

```
Interface: (in .h)

@interface globalFunction : NSObject
{
    int nbr;
}


@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger myInt;

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;

- (void)eventCount:(NSString*) eventName;

@end




Implementation: (in .m)

@implementation globalFunction


#pragma mark - Singleton Class instance
/*
 * Singelton instance of globalFunction
 */
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static globalFunction *_instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _instance = [[globalFunction alloc] init];
    });

    return _instance;
}



- (void)eventCount:(NSString *)eventName{


    _myInt ++;
    NSLog(@"Event name %@ and the count %d",eventName, _myInt);
}


@end
```

and can access using:

```
[[globalFunction sharedInstance] eventCount:@"Ev"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should you a singleton object, which will be alive and shared between all your objects. Then you can keep there a counter as a property, take a look to this post: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Wish it helps!